# Sequence by date, add date before and date after postgresql with subquery

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I haven't found a similar question but would be glad to be pointed to one or answered...

**Background**
I have a database: DB1 of vehicles with 6 mln rows for each month. And DB2 of events with 400k rows for the whole yr. Both contain locations (x,y). I am trying to cross reference them by dates and distances in postGIS. Ideally I'd like to have for each event in DB2 an histogram of distances from vehicles in DB1 that were there say before and after 1 hour. But beforehand I'm prepping the DB1 and thus my question

**Question**
I would like to add for each vehicle in DB1 `time_prev` , `time_next` and `time_sequence` for each day as here

[image: DB1 before], [image: DB1 after]
link to a chunk of cleaned data from DB1: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_mz1JqQJu4VZ7iJ6WLezH7rZhurOIPDQu3flv8Qz058/edit?usp=sharing

*I'm still not sure how to continue from there so ideas would be welcome...*

Comment: Read about `LEAD()/LAG()` window functions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-window.html).

```
select 
    *, 
    lag(timestamp) over wa time_prev, 
    lead(timestamp) over wa time_next,
    to_char(timestamp, 'yyyymmdd') || to_char(row_number() over wd, 'fm0009') time_sequence
from db1
window 
    wa as (partition by vehicle_id order by objectid),
    wd as (partition by vehicle_id, timestamp::date order by objectid);


 objectid | vehicle_id |      timestamp      |      time_prev      |      time_next      | time_sequence 
----------+------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------
        1 |          1 | 2009-06-01 11:57:43 |                     | 2009-06-01 11:09:16 | 200906010001
        4 |          1 | 2009-06-01 11:09:16 | 2009-06-01 11:57:43 | 2009-06-01 10:16:28 | 200906010002
        6 |          1 | 2009-06-01 10:16:28 | 2009-06-01 11:09:16 | 2009-06-01 09:33:01 | 200906010003
       11 |          1 | 2009-06-01 09:33:01 | 2009-06-01 10:16:28 | 2009-06-01 11:30:19 | 200906010004
       12 |          1 | 2009-06-01 11:30:19 | 2009-06-01 09:33:01 |                     | 200906010005
        2 |          2 | 2009-06-01 10:42:19 |                     | 2009-06-01 11:02:23 | 200906010001
        3 |          2 | 2009-06-01 11:02:23 | 2009-06-01 10:42:19 | 2009-06-01 10:32:19 | 200906010002
        7 |          2 | 2009-06-01 10:32:19 | 2009-06-01 11:02:23 | 2009-06-01 09:20:31 | 200906010003
        9 |          2 | 2009-06-01 09:20:31 | 2009-06-01 10:32:19 | 2009-06-01 11:56:23 | 200906010004
       13 |          2 | 2009-06-01 11:56:23 | 2009-06-01 09:20:31 |                     | 200906010005
        5 |          3 | 2009-06-01 11:56:47 |                     | 2009-06-01 10:52:19 | 200906010001
        8 |          3 | 2009-06-01 10:52:19 | 2009-06-01 11:56:47 | 2009-06-01 11:06:39 | 200906010002
       10 |          3 | 2009-06-01 11:06:39 | 2009-06-01 10:52:19 |                     | 200906010003
(13 rows)
```

Comment: this worked, tnx) took 61 min for ~6 mln rows. any ideas how to continue?

Comment: You can make the query faster by defining the index `create index on db1 (vehicle_id, objectid)`. I think you can ask a new question about the next step (It's not quite clear for me).