# histogram of distances between multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, postgis

following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787030/sequence-by-date-add-date-before-and-date-after-postgresql-with-subquery/37787562?noredirect=1#comment63051307_37787562) here is a sequel

**Background** I have 2 databases: events (400k rows for the whole yr) and cars (6 mln rows for each month). a smaller sample is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DMbphMtb5iZtpPC7YtRLWQLvTMoC9qzBp2iknHFO0uA/edit?usp=sharing) looking like this [image: input db]
events have locations x y. cars have car_id, time_now, time_prev, time_next as well as locations x y.

**Desired result** would be to have an histogram of distances from each event  to all cars at time of the event ±delta time.
Alternatively would be good to have for each event a table of distances to each car at time of the event ±delta. And if nothing works, perhaps add to the table events columns closest_car_0min , closest_car_5min, closest_car_15min,closest_car_30min.

I thought to use `ST_Distance` to calculate the distances (PostGIS extension).

I also had created time_prev and time_next because I thought to check whether time of the event events.date_ ±1 hour falls within the interval from time_prev to time_now or from time_now to time_next.

**Question**: well, how on earth do i do this?

**Update** to clarify, I added desired results to [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DMbphMtb5iZtpPC7YtRLWQLvTMoC9qzBp2iknHFO0uA/edit?usp=sharing) looking like this [image: results]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer. The following worked:

```
--create empty table for results and fix key
create table results 
(
    resultID serial NOT NULL,
    vehicle_id numeric(10,0),
    eventid numeric(10,0),
    deltaMIN interval MINUTE,
    distance_m32138 double precision,
    eventtime timestamp without time zone, 
    time_now timestamp without time zone,
    time_prev timestamp without time zone, 
    time_next timestamp without time zone   
)
;
alter table results add CONSTRAINT results_pkey PRIMARY KEY (resultID);

INSERT INTO results
( vehicle_id, eventid, deltaMIN, distance_m32138, eventtime, time_now, time_prev,time_next)
select 
    vehicle_id,
    eventid,
    deltaMIN,
    ST_Distance (
        ST_Transform(toy_events.geom ,32138), 
        ST_Transform(toy_cars.geom ,32138)
        ) AS distance_m32138,
    eventtime, time_now, time_prev, time_next
from
    toy_events, 
    toy_cars,
    deltas
where
    eventtime between time_prev and time_next 
    or
    (
        eventtime - deltamin between time_prev and time_now
        or
        eventtime + deltamin between time_now and time_next
     )    
;
select * from results;
```